# SQL Server : query that will transpose data into a horizontal or summary (pivot without aggregate function)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data as shown below, and I want to create a summary. Please kindly see the below desired output.

**DATA**

```
ID   TIMEIN               TIMEOUT
1    10/01/2013 8:00AM    10/01/2013 5:00PM
1    10/02/2013 8:00AM    10/01/2013 5:00PM
1    10/03/2013 8:00AM    10/01/2013 5:00PM
1    10/04/2013 8:00AM    10/01/2013 5:00PM
1    10/05/2013 8:00AM    10/01/2013 5:00PM
3    10/01/2013 8:10AM    10/01/2013 5:00PM
3    10/02/2013 8:02AM    10/01/2013 5:00PM
3    10/03/2013 8:04AM    10/01/2013 5:00PM
3    10/04/2013 8:20AM    10/01/2013 5:00PM
3    10/05/2013 8:03AM    10/01/2013 5:00PM
4    10/01/2013 8:10AM    10/01/2013 5:00PM
4    10/02/2013 8:02AM    10/01/2013 5:00PM
4    10/03/2013 8:04AM    10/01/2013 5:00PM
4    10/04/2013 8:20AM    10/01/2013 5:00PM
4    10/05/2013 8:03AM    10/01/2013 5:00PM
```

**DESIRED output**

```
ID     10/01/2013     10/02/2013       10/03/2013       10/04/2013      10/05/2013
       IN     OUT     IN      OUT      IN      OUT      IN     OUT      IN   OUT
1     8:00AM  5:00PM  8:00AM  5:00PM   8:00AM  5:00PM   8:00AM  5:00PM  8:00AM  5:00PM
3     8:10AM  5:00PM  8:02AM  5:00PM   8:04AM  5:00PM   8:20AM  5:00PM  8:03AM  5:00PM
4     8:10AM  5:00PM  8:02AM  5:00PM   8:04AM  5:00PM   8:20AM  5:00PM  8:03AM  5:00PM
```

OR

```
ID     10/01/2013      10/02/2013       10/03/2013       10/04/2013      10/05/2013
1     8:00AM 5:00PM   8:00AM 5:00PM    8:00AM 5:00PM    8:00AM 5:00PM   8:00AM 5:00PM
3     8:10AM 5:00PM   8:02AM 5:00PM    8:04AM 5:00PM    8:20AM 5:00PM   8:03AM 5:00PM
4     8:10AM 5:00PM   8:02AM 5:00PM    8:04AM 5:00PM    8:20AM 5:00PM   8:03AM 5:00PM
```

How can I get this output using the data provided?

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Is there any other identifier in the table except ID? Ehm, the one that would identify the row, like a PK or something people usually use for that purpose?

Comment: Your desired output is not a relation. Tabular results in SQL Server can't have a single value `10/01/2013` spanning two columns.

Comment: if not.... any suggestion or wild idea on how to solve this?

Comment: You'll want to look at `PIVOT`.

Comment: PIVOT on a know points in time over that data such as day/month/weeks and years.